# Error - Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to ask why am I getting this error:

> Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object

with the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY Author";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {...
```

I have used `echo $sql` to look if the problem lies there, but there is no problem. My SQL looks fine.

I have tried to use `Prepared Statements` and got other errors too.

The line which gives the error is the one with the `if` statement.

Any ideas?

Comment: The query failed use error reporting to see why.

Comment: Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your query to find out why it failed. I'm guessing there may be something wrong with `$table_name`, or that table doesn't have a column Author.

Comment: A prepared statement wouldn't actually help you here because you can't bind table names.

Comment: You can try var_dump($result); and check If this is an object. Probably it's a mysql error. Try mysql_error() to see what is it.

Comment: @lumadev They'll need http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php `mysql_` wont work with `mysqli`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better (non-error checking) pattern to follow IMO:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY Author";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if (!empty($result)) {
```

You should also consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: Why is this better? Isn't this just bypassing the problem and the OP will never get results?

Comment: Yes, non-error-checking. It's better IMO because it handles lots common failure cases in php and is readable. If the call returns `false`, or `null`, or an empty string `''` or and empty array `[]` all can be handled by `empty()` correctly.